# HTML Pre tag, how to word wrap in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, pre

I have a large number of transcriptions on a family history website.  The transcripts use the PRE tag to control the formatting.  However, on some of them, the lines are long and go over the border lines.

I am using the following CSS:

```
pre    {font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    line-height: 1.75em;
 white-space: pre-line;
}
```

This works fine in Internet Explorer and Firefox, but not in Chrome.  I've tried: white-space: pre-wrap; and some other examples while googling this problem, but none have worked for me.  I'm just wondering what I should use to get this to work in Chrome.

A link to an example is here:  http://www.iomfhs.im/resources/wills/1685_008.html

Comment: You say that it goes over the border lines, but I see no issue with the provided link. Do *CTRL+F5* and see if that helps, if not, can you describe the issue more detailed?

Comment: i didn't see what your saying in that page ... Chrome Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: OMG what a numpty I am!  I have always used F5 to refresh, and when it wasn't happening, I thought my code wasn't working, but I used CTRL F5 and it has!  Thank you for pointing that out to me.  Problem solved that wasn't a problem.